# Facebook Comments iFrame height limited when using HTML file not URL

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-comments

I'm loading a facebook comment page from a local file, not a URL.

(Reason: It's for a Mobile App & I need a template file for creating multiple comment pages)

The FB comments load but the iFrame is always the same fixed height which limits the view to the first comment only.
It's a browser & platform independent problem from the many tests I've ran.

If I add the html file to my web site and access it as a URL it works perfectly.

Can anyone shed light on why the iFrame height for FB comments would be fixed due to the source being a local file and not fixed when a URL?

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Public Comments</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>(function(d, s, id) {
             var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
             if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
             js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
             js.src = "http://connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=XXXXXXXXXXXX";
             fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
             }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
    <div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://my-web-site.help/dir/#ALIAS" " data-num-posts="10" data-mobile="true"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Can anyone shed light on why the iFrame height for FB comments would be fixed due to the source being a local file and not fixed when a URL?

Most likely because the cross-domain communication the JS SDK has to do to be able to adjust the height of the iframe element in your site does not work in such a scenario.

Comment: Embedding FB comments in mobile Apps is well cover here on Stackoverflow & else where and this method is the most often suggested one. I've not seen any of these posts mention iframe height issues with the file method. This leads me to think that FB have changed something recently. Any workarounds?